# Использование WITH для HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Пытаюсь написать запрос на `hql`, который будет вытаскивать `b` только тогда когда оно будет совпадать с `а`

```
 select
     a.code,
     b.name as name 
 from 
    a, 
    b left join b1 WITH a.id = b.aId,
```

Comment: А проблема в чем? По запросу - предполагаю как то так - select
     a.code,
     b.name as name 
 from 
    a 
     left join b ON a.id = b.aId,

Comment: С 'on' не работает. "Unexpected token 'on' "

Comment: Посмотрите этот пост - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004996/unexpected-token-in-hql

Comment: В этом посте предлагают сделать саб селект, мне он не подходит, так как мне нужно вытащить сразу несколько полей.